# Extracting contents from an XML file with BeautifulSoup on Python

Tags: python, xml, validation, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have an XML structure like this:

```
<Trainers>
 <Trainer name="VisitorID" value=" NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231"/>
 <Trainer name="VisitorNumber" value="BR-76594823-009922"/>
 <Trainer name="ServerIndex" value="213122"/>
 <Trainer name="VisitorPolicyID" value="ETR1234123"/>
</Trainers>
```

I want to extract the values based on the Trainer names. So basically something like this:

`NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231` from the `VisitorID` , `BR-76594823-009922` from `VisitorNumber` and so on..

I also want to see if I can extract `<Trainers>` if that is possible.

I can do this on Pandas with '`read_xml`' and get a table, but I want to get these values individually so I can validate the table created from Pandas.

Here is what I tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(Trainee.xml, 'xml')
soup.find_all({"Trainer name": "VisitorID"})
soup.find_all({"Trainer name": "VisitorNumber"})
soup.find_all({"Trainer name": "ServerIndex"})
soup.find_all({"Trainer name": "VisitorPolicyID"})
```

I expected this to work but these are giving me empty arrays `[]`
Is there something I am missing here? When I parse it through Pandas with `read_xml` I get a proper table but individually I am getting an empty array.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get all `<Trainers>` and from this all `name`/`value` pairs:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = """\
<Trainers>
 <Trainer name="VisitorID" value=" NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231"/>
 <Trainer name="VisitorNumber" value="BR-76594823-009922"/>
 <Trainer name="ServerIndex" value="213122"/>
 <Trainer name="VisitorPolicyID" value="ETR1234123"/>
</Trainers>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")

for item in soup.select("Trainers"):
    for trainer in item.select("Trainer"):
        print(trainer["name"], trainer["value"])
```

Prints:

```
VisitorID  NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231
VisitorNumber BR-76594823-009922
ServerIndex 213122
VisitorPolicyID ETR1234123
```

---

If you want to construct dataframe from the data, you can use this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {t["name"]: t["value"] for t in item.select("Trainer")}
        for item in soup.select("Trainers")
    ]
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                VisitorID       VisitorNumber ServerIndex VisitorPolicyID
0   NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231  BR-76594823-009922      213122      ETR1234123
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It really helped! I just want to ask an additional question regarding this problem. So I want to retrieve the values based on the trainer names. I want to input 'VisitorID' into BeautifulSoup, and would like to get 'NPRoiuKL213kiolkm2231' back as the output. Do you know what I can change to this answer to get this? Thank you so much!